# KeystoneJS as back-end with Flutter as front-end

Tags: flutter, keystonejs, flutter-web

Is it possible/feasible to use [KeystoneJS](https://www.keystonejs.com) along with a front-end developed in [Flutter for web](https://flutter.dev/web)? Would it make sense to do so? Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`Keystonejs` is any other backend which provides headless cms capability. You can use this like any other backend using GraphQL client if available in Flutter.

I see Flutter does [support http request](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) you can use this feature to call GraphQL using plain http query (`http` package). example query to get all users from `User` list

```js
var client = http.Client();
try {
  var response = await client.post('https://keystoneproject.com/admin/api',
      body: { 'query': 'query { allUsers { id name email isAdmin }}' });
 // this gives you result in JSON format `{ data: { allusers { id: "id value", name: "name of user", email: "email of user", isAdmin: false } }
  print(await client.get(response.bodyFields['data']));
} finally {
  client.close();
}
```

body should also contain `variable` field if your query has any parameter (see GraphQL reference on how that work, I don't think that is scope of the answer)